# warning: integer constant is too large for its type

Tags: c, arguments, constants, max, unsigned-long-long-int

how to find the correct type for largest number ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
/**
 * factor_prime - prints the prime factors of a number
 * @n: number
 */

void factor_prime(unsigned long long n)
{
    long i;
    long inter = n;

    printf("n : %lld\n", n);
    for (i  = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            n = n / i;
            printf("%ld=%lld*%ld\n", inter, n, i);
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    factor_prime(1718944270642558716715u);
}
```

output   : 3397071787570416427=35568825191561*95507

expected : 1718944270642558716715=343788854128511743343*5

how to fix ?

Comment: Working with really big numbers (aka "bignums") isn't as easy as working with ordinary integers.  Usually you need to use an external library; one popular one is [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Unsigned long long is basically 8 bytes and can store values from 0 to 18,446,744,073 709,551,615. Your number is bigger, so there is the warning

Comment: For starters, you should use `ull`, not `u` for an `unsigned long long`, but that's probably not enough. See previous comment or try using a `uint64_t`. Also, the algorithm you are using is way too slow for that factorization. `i` should have the same type of `n`, too.

Comment: By the way, 343788854128511743343 is not a prime number.  The factorization I would expect is 1718944270642558716715 = 5 × 7 × 29 × 10771 × 157231561910911.

Comment: In the end, though, you probably don't need to worry about making your program work for numbers this big.  Factoring big numbers is really, really hard.    For now I would recommend that you fix your programs other problems, and accept that you're not going to be able to factor a number larger than 18446744073709551615 with it.

Comment: As an example of what I'm talking about, try factoring the number 18446743979220271189.  It fits in 64 bits just fine, but factoring it is going to take a while.  (For an easier problem, that'll probably only take a few minutes, try 110167479599457199.)

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for your answer. My program find a first prime number and exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a too big integer constant that can not be represented in any object of an integer type.

Consider this demonstration program.

#include <stdio.h>

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%llu\n", ULLONG_MAX );
    printf( "%" PRIuMAX "\n", UINTMAX_MAX );
}
```

Its output is

```
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
```

The outputted constant contains only `20` digits while your constant `1718944270642558716715u` that you are trying to use contains `22` digits.

Pay attention to that in any case your function is incorrect. The function parameter has the type `unsigned long long` that you are assigning  to a variable of the signed type `long`

```
void factor_prime(unsigned long long n)
{
    long i;
    long inter = n;
    //...
```

As you are trying to pass a very big number then the assignment results in getting an invalid value.

Comment: Thanks, i better understand now. i'm beginner in C

Comment: @iamMAHAM Well, then select the best answer and your reputation will be increased.:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're passing a value i.e. `1718944270642558716715u` which is out of range for the `unsigned long long` numeric limit.

You can check the numeric limit of a type using:

- **For c++**

```
std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() // 18446744073709551615
```

- **For C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{   
    printf("%llu", ULONG_LONG_MAX); // 18446744073709551615
}
```